# Pass XML value from one page other page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I want to pass an XML value from one page to another in a better way.

I am getting this XML value from API:

```
<hotelist>
  <hotel>
    <hotelId>109</hotelId>
    <hotelName>Hotel Sara</hotelName>
    <location>UK,london</location>
  </hotel>
  <hotel>
    <hotelId>110</hotelId>
    <hotelName>Radha park</hotelName>
    <location>UK,london</location>
  </hotel>
  <hotel>
    <hotelId>111</hotelId>
    <hotelName>Hotel Green park</hotelName>
    <location>chennai,India</location>
  </hotel>
  <hotel>
    <hotelId>112</hotelId>
    <hotelName>Hotel Mauria</hotelName>
    <location>paris,France</location>
  </hotel>   
</hotelist>
```

I want to pass one hotel:

```
<hotel>
  <hotelId>112</hotelId>
  <hotelName>Hotel Mauria</hotelName>
  <location>paris,France</location>
</hotel>
```

to next page.

I am using the Nokogiri gem for parsing XML. For the API next call I have to pass the one hotel to the next page. Which is the best method?

Note: This is just a sample. There are a lot of information bound with the hotel including available room, discount and so on.

Comment: I don't what the problem is. Please provide some code and narrow your question down a bit.

Comment: xml above is used for listing page . from there i have to take those information to next page when click the particular hotel . I have to take the particular hotel info to next page .

Comment: I recommend you model a Hotel, extracting the data you need. Don't think of it as passing XML between views.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as far as I'm getting this, you are searching for some hotels through a third party service, and then displaying a list. After the user clicks on an item you displaying the detail info
for the hotel.

The easiest way would be having another API endpoint, which can provide the detail information for a specific Hotel id. I guess you're dealing with some really bad API and that's not the case.

There are couple of other options (ordered by complexity level):

1. There is really not much data and it should fit an simple GET request, so you can just encode the respective hotel information into the URL parameter for the detail
   page. Assuming you have set up resourcefull routing and have already parsed the XML into `@hotels` array of some Hotel models/structs or the like:

   ```
   <% @hotels.each |hotel| do %>
     <% # generates <a href=/hotels/112?hotelName=Hotel+Mauria&location=paris%2C+France'>Hotel Mauria</a>
     <%= link_to hotel.hotelName hotel_path(hotel.hotelId, hotelName: hotel.hotelName, location: hotel.location) %>
   <% end %>
   ```
2. Encode the info into the respective Hotel DOM elements as data-attributes:

   ```
   <div class="hotel" data-id="112" data-hotel-name="Mauria" ... />
   ```

   Then render the detail page on the client side without the server entirely by subscribing to a click event, reading the info stored in the respective data attributes and replace the list with the detail div.

   If the third party API is public you could even move the search problem entirely to the client.
3. Introduce caching of search requests on the server. Then just pick a hotel from the cache
   by its id. This would be saving you from doing to much third party requests from your Rails app, which is a weak spot of Rails if deployed on a typical multi-process server.

   The simplest way of doing this, would be storing the last search result in a user session, but that
   would be probably too memory heavy. If you can expect the hotel information not to change frequently, you could cache it by the query parameters. You could also use some smart caching store like redis and index the entire hotel information, than performing the search on the cache and only in case of the cache miss hit the third party API. But always remember, caching is easy, expiring is hard.

"[Everyone should be using low level caching in Rails](http://robotmay.com/post/23161612605/everyone-should-be-using-low-level-caching)" could be interesting for implementing a cache.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind passing all that information in query parameters:

```
links = doc.xpath('//hotel').map do |hotel|
  hash = Hash.from_xml(hotel.to_xml)
  url_for({controller: 'x', action: 'y'}.merge(hash))
  # or if you have your link as a string
  # "#{link_string}?#{hash.to_param}"
end
```

If you want to create a link for just one hotel, extract the relevant XML (e.g., using the process described in Uri's answer), and then generate the link as above.

Assuming you have the API XML ready before you render the current page, you could render the relevant hotel data into form fields so that you could `post` to the next page, something like:

```
<%= fields_for :hotel do |hf| %>
  <% hf.hidden_field :hotelId, value: hash['hotel']['hotelId'] %>
  # ...
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

One optimum way to achieve this is as suggested by Mark Thomas.

However if you still need to pass data between pages you can put all the xml information as a string in a session variable and use it on next page.